# Avoid Object Being Deallocated Without Adding Property/iVar to UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, dealloc

I have a custom class/object that handles gestures and conducts animations for a given view using a CADisplayLink. In its simplest form my class looks something like follows:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject

@property (strong) UIView *someView;

@end
```

When I add the following code to my view controller....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SomeClass *someClass = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
    someClass.someView = someView;
}
```

... I was anticipating my someClass object would be retained for the life of the view controller, since I am using a strong reference to someView.

However someClass is immediately deallocated.

I am already aware that I can overcome the deallocation simply by adding someClass as a property (or indeed iVar) of the view controller however I would ideally like to avoid this extra work...

so is there anyway I can have my class retained until either the view or view controller its associated with are deallocated?

**EDIT**

UIGestureRecognizer objects are an exmaple of a class that doesn't get deallocated when I associate them with a view...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    [someView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}
// tapGestureRecognizer still lives
```

Presumably this is because the UIView takes owner ship of the UIGestureRecognizer object.  Is there anyway to achieve this with my class and a UIView category?  I.e....

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SomeClass *someClass = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
    [someView addSomeClass:someClass];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to associate the object with a UIView in the same way a UIGestureRecognizer does then this is *technically* possible using associatedObjects as follows (but I'm not sure I'd advocate this approach since associatedObjects are often frowned upon)...

**SomeClass.h**

```
@class SomeClass;


@interface UIView (SomeClass)

- (void)addSomeClass:(SomeClass *)someClass;
- (void)removeSomeClass:(SomeClass *)someClass;

@end


@interface SomeClass : NSObject

@property (strong) UIView *someView;

@end
```

**SomeClass.m**

```
#import "SomeClass.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>


@implementation UIView (AssociatedObject)

- (void)addSomeClass:(SomeClass *)someClass
{
    NSMutableArray *someClasses = [self someClasses];
    if (someClasses == nil) {
        someClasses = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self setSomeClasses:someClasses];
    }
    [someClasses addObject:someClass];
}

- (void)removeSomeClass:(SomeClass *)someClass
{
    NSMutableArray *someClasses = [self someClasses];
    if (someClasses != nil) {
        [someClasses removeObject:someClass];
        if (someClasses.count == 0) {
            [self setSomeClasses:nil];
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - Private Methods

- (NSMutableArray *)someClasses
{
    return (NSMutableArray *)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(someClasses));
}

- (void)setSomeClasses:(NSMutableArray *)someClasses
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(someClasses), someClasses, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

@end


@implementation SomeClass

@end
```

**Implementation**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SomeClass *someClass = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
    someClass.someView = someView;
    [someView addSomeClass:someClass];
}
```

Some further reading on associatedObjects from NSHipster...

http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/

Comment: Thanks for actually answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

But you can declare SomeClass instance instead of property like this:

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    SomeClass* _someClass;
}

...


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _someClass = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
    _someClass.someView = someView;
}
```

Comment: Apologies, should have specifically said property or iVar (I thought this was obvious).  This is exactly what I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SomeClass` instance is holding a strong reference to the `someView`, but nothing is holding a reference to the `SomeClass` instance except the local variable inside your `viewDidLoad` message, so as soon as the method exits, that instance can be deallocated. As that was the object holding the only reference to your `UIView` the view can also be deallocated.

Your only options are to store the reference to the `SomeClass` object in an instance variable (or iVar) as stosha suggested or in a property. Properties are the preferred method and with automatic synthesis they don't take much more effort than a local variable declaration.

You can declare the property inside the .m file so that it isn't visible to other classes that reference your `ViewController` class -

In your `ViewController.m` file -

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) SomeClass *someClass;

@end

@implementation ViewController

...

 (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.someClass = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
    self.someClass.someView = someView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the informative comment, however this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Ok, then the short answer is "no". Yes, you could modify view to hold the reference, but seems to be unnecessarily complex compare to a simple property